# join mysql on a date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables that I wish to join on a date range. Table 1's date only vary on year and month while table 2 vary on multiple days.

```
Table 1
pur_date      product
2015-06-01    shirt
2015-06-01    shoe
2015-05-01    shoe
2015-04-01    purse
2015-04-01    bag
2014-05-01    key

Table 2
chk_date     cost  
2015-07-15    10
2015-06-30     8
2015-04-30     5
2015-07-29     9
2014-06-25     6
2015-05-30     9
2015-05-15     4 
2015-05-28     8
```

I want to join on date such that I want (count number of costs that are >8) / (total number of costs)*100 where (chk_date - pur_date) is <= 62  (i.e. <= 2 months of pur_date)

So for my final table, I should get this output of unique pur dates and the (count number of costs that are >8) / (total number of costs)*100 As percent :

```
table 3
    pur_date     percent
    2015-06-01      2/4*100
    2015-05-01      1/5*100
```

How can I write the join clause for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
select pur_date,
       (select avg(cost > 8)
        from table2
        where chk_date <= pur_date - interval 2 month
       ) as percent
from (select distinct pur_date from table1) t;
```

Comment: I made a small mistake earlier where the signs were opposite to each other, have changed them both to <= 62 now

Comment: not sure what this line mean `chk_date > pur_date - interval 2 month`

Comment: It is supposed to be:  "(chk_date - pur_date) is <= 62 (i.e. <= 2 months of pur_date)", but I think the logic was backwards.

Comment: could you also explain why the `t` was necessary?

Comment: `t` is necessary because MySQL requires table aliases for subqueries in the `from` clause.

Comment: Thanks! i have an extension to this question here, would appreciate your help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306792/join-mysql-on-a-date-range/31306841#31306841